# Rearrange tuple of tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples, transpose

I have a tuple of tuples:

```
t = ((1, 'one'), (2, 'two'))
```

I need it in the following format:

```
((1, 2), ('one', 'two'))
```

How can I convert it? I can do something like:

```
digits     =  tuple ( digit for digit, word in t )
words      =  tuple ( word for digit, word in t )
rearranged =  tuple ( digits, words )
```

But that seems not elegant, I suppose there's a more straightforward solution.

Comment: This is called transposing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the following:

```
tuple(zip(*t))
```